# Unity toggling components

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I will try to be as clean as I can.

1. I have different types of enemies which have different type of scripts that control their beheviour.
2. I want to disable these scripts with another script.

But the thing is I don't want to use a certain type of component. For example:

We have a bomber controller for a bomber enemy and a charger controller for a charger enemy.

If I store one of these components in a public component from another script I can't turn them on or off with enabled property. Because Component class doesn't have an enabled property.

I can use specified components but I don't want to. I can store the scripts in their type of component like a bomber controller for a bomber controller but this will change depends on the enemy type.

As I said for each of the enemies I have different scripts that controls their beheviours.

To sum up I want this:

```
public Component ControllerScript (will be set from the editor)

insomemethod(){
   ControllerScript.enabled = false;
}
```

So any ideas? What can I use instead of Component above?

Comment: Why not use `MonoBehaviour` as usual?

Comment: I can't believe this one was that easy... I fixed the problem but made a huge mess. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered a common base class for your different enemy controller scripts? The reason why Unity's default components (like different kinds of colliders) can be disabled is because they inherit from a common base class with an `enabled` property that then inherits from `Component`.

For example, you might have a class like this:

```cs
public class EnemyController : Component
{
    public void enabled { get; set; } = true;

    // Other common methods - maybe virtual ones if your controllers
    // are executed in the same way?
}
```

Then your child classes could look like:

```cs
public class BomberController : EnemyController { }
public class ChargerController : EnemyController { }
```

And lastly, you can reference the base class in your public variable:

```cs
public EnemyController ControllerScript

insomemethod(){
   ControllerScript.enabled = false;
}
```

That does require you to manually define what `enabled` does though, and your classes might not appear as desired in the editor. If you want to avoid all those headaches, consider inheriting from `MonoBehaviour` instead - this is usually the recommended base class for user-written components.

Comment: Can the enabled property in the EnemyController class, function like the enabled property we use for other components? Or do I have set that up too?

Comment: Each of Unity's own components behaves differently when enabled is set to false - for example, Colliders will no longer interact with other Colliders, while Renderers will no longer draw to the screen. In the same way, you'll have to define how your own component behaves when it is disabled. That's where adding common base methods can be helpful - if you have a common base method that executes logic, you can gate its contents behind `enabled` to prevent the controller from doing anything if it is disabled.

Comment: But in general, I think the recommended way to meet your needs is just to inherit from MonoBehaviour. I'll add that to my answer - have you considered that?